# Upgrade to Rails 4.2.0: string literals in where conditions wrapped into quotation marks

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

During an upgrade of `rails` version in my application from `4.1.8` to `4.2.0`, I have encountered the following issue.

String literals in `where` conditions are now additionally wrapped into quotation marks, which
then become part of a query string, delivering no valid results anymore. This happens only for database fields of a `text` type (`varchar` fields are not affected). I am using a MySQL database.

```
> Table.where(column: 'data')
[08:19:20.822552] Table Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `table`.* FROM `table`
WHERE `table`.`column` = '\"data\"'
```

Now, if you have a row containing `data` value in a column row, this condition will no longer match (obviously, `"data"` is not a match anymore).

In Rails 4.1.8 everything worked perfectly fine:

```
 > Table.where(column: 'data')
 [08:19:58.303366] Table Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `table`.* FROM `table`
 WHERE `table`.`column` = 'data'
```

I don't know if this is a default or a configurable behaviour. I somehow haven't found a corresponding release note on that. I would be very grateful for any suggestions on what has changed and what is the best way to fix it.

Many thanks for help!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this - can you reproduce in a freshly generated app (maybe some non rails 4.2 compatible gem) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this way:

```
Table.where("column=?", 'data')
```

I guess this will work.

Comment: Yes, it works! Could that be considered a preferred solution for this problem, or does it seem more like a hack (from a ruby's best practices perspective)?

Comment: This is a preferred solution as far as rails best practices are concerned.